# Split tar.bz2 file and extract each individually

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar

Can I split a large tar.bz2 file into several smaller files and extract those small tar.bz2 files individually in Ubuntu?

Thanks,

Comment: You want to create a set of self-contained .tar.bz2 files each of which can be extracted separately from the other? That's a lot less trivial than just doing a split on the overall archive, and is more of a superuser-type question rather than a stackoverflow one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's easily possible. A `.tar.bz2` is a single stream, it doesn't have an index like `zip` that would allow skipping to the start of a particular file within the archive. You can split the file using `split` utility, and than `cat` the parts and extract them (you can do this via stdin to avoid re-creating the pasted file on disk). The first fragment will be possible to extract separately (except for the last file in it which will probably be damaged), but further fragments will not be usable without the onces that come before them.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the `--multi-volume` option:

```
tar -cf archive.tar --multi-volume --tape-length 1024 folder
```

Unfortunately, it does not work with compressed archives:

```
tar: Cannot use multi-volume compressed archives
```

You could compress volumes individually, but the size of the volumes might vary considerably.

Hope it solves your use-case.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if help is still needed on this, but I have found a method that will at least allow you to use the split command along with tar (bz2) compression. As far as extracting each file individually, this option sees the files as a part of a whole (much like Winzip does when spanning multiple volumes...if one of the volumes is missing, the archive as a whole is corrupt). With that said:

Creating split files. Note that this will create files sequentially with "aa, ab, ac" designations:

tar -cv(z/j)f - (files to be archived) | split -b(size in bytes, such as 4000m) - (name for output archive file)

Extracting split files:

cat (file*) | bzcat/gunzip(-d) | tar (t/x)v(j/z)f -

(If you used the "j" option, bzcat would go inside the pipes) or  (If you used the "z" option, gunzip would go inside the pipes). You may also need to use "gunzip -d" within these two pipes if you get an error

Comment: I had to `cat file.tar.bz2* | bzcat > myfile.tar` to get the tar file first as piping to the tar didn't work for me (Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 0):

TO split the file into multiple files.

It will automatically  create files of size 1.1GB, if your tar is bigger in size, you can increase the number, for an example 1000 {2..1000} or you can increase the input to tape-length argument.

```
tar --tape-length=1048576 -cMv --file=tar_archive.{tar,tar-{2..100}} backup.tar.lzma
```

but as @michal said, it is not possible to extract them individually.

```
tar: backup.tar.lzma: Cannot extract -- file is continued from another volume
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```